# how to enable button when all textfields filled in tableviewcell(SWIFT)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift4

I want to enable the button in the viewcontroller when I fill in the textfield in the tableviewcell.

I don't know how to solve the problem.

Sorry. I am immature in English.

1. button(viewController) isEnable = false
2. fill textfields(inside tableviewcell)
3. button(viewController) isEnable = true

[image]

1. ViewController

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet var viewLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var clickBtn: UIButton!

    var cell: CustomTableViewCell!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.clickBtn.isEnabled = false
        cell.textFieldCell.addTarget(self, action: #selector(editingChanged), for: .editingChanged)
        cell.textFieldCell2.addTarget(self, action: #selector(editingChanged), for: .editingChanged)
    }

    @objc func editingChanged(sender: UITextField) {

        sender.text = sender.text?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)

        guard
            let text1 = cell.textFieldCell.text, !text1.isEmpty,
            let text2 = cell.textFieldCell2.text, !text2.isEmpty
            else
        {
            self.clickBtn.isEnabled = false
            return
        }
        clickBtn.isEnabled = true
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell
        return cell
    }
}
```

2. CustomTableView

```
import UIKit

class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var myLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var textFieldCell: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var textFieldCell2: UITextField!
}
```

Comment: Check if this helps. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52063413/enable-button-if-textview-and-textfields-are-filled/52063871#52063871

Comment: Inside viewDidLoad cell value will nil and its refer to only last cell so don't put Global  cell. you meed to maintain array to check tex field value is field or not because of table view's  reusable cell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the table view contains only one cell why do you use a table view at all?
And if you really need to use a table view why don't you use a **static** cell?

---

A simple solution is to move the target/action code from `viewDidLoad` into the `didSet` property observer of the cell

```
var cell: CustomTableViewCell! {
    didSet {
        cell.textFieldCell.addTarget(self, action: #selector(editingChanged), for: .editingChanged)
        cell.textFieldCell2.addTarget(self, action: #selector(editingChanged), for: .editingChanged)
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.clickBtn.isEnabled = false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use delegate.

```
protocol CustomTableViewCellDelegate  { 
    func editingChanged(_ String: yourString)    
}
```

In table view cell

```
class TableViewCell: UITaleViewCell { 
    // declare the delegate 
    var delegate: CustomTableViewCellDelegate? 
    // and pass it like this from where you want to pass 
    delegate?.editingChanged(cookie) 
}
```

For using in tableViewController. first assign the delegate to self in cell for row at indexpath method. Then implement the delegate in it.

```
extension CustomTableViewController: CustomTableViewCellDelegate { 
    func editingChanged(String: yourString) { 
    // use it accordingly 
    } 
}
```